# Jetpack Compose RangeSlider with gradient activeTrackColor

Tags: android, android-jetpack, rangeslider

In my jetpack compose app I use a RangeSlider for selecting dates:

[image: date range slider]

The active track should use gradient color, e.g. black in the middle and red on the outer sides:

[image: gradient color example]

Is this possible using standard RangeSlider?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The RangeSlider is very limited in its capabilities and only accepts Color instances.

For normal sliders you can use [Colorful Sliders](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Colorful-Sliders), but they do not support range sliders as of today.